# Force download maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, nexus, maven-metadata

So my job has 2 parts. The `first part` downloads all the required maven artifacts from a central online repository. The `second part` uses the download folder as an online repository(by changing URL from central repo to local folder) to build our product.

But there are certain artifacts which do not have a `maven-metadata.xml` after the first part of the job. As a result, the second part fails. I don't want to hardcode the online repo and curl as it's not what we're looking for. Neither do I want to copy some other `maven-metadata.xml` and edit my changes. Also, I cant give the `offline` option during build, as I do need the artifacts to be picked up from my `local repo`(downloads).

Any solution to this? Thanks IA.

Comment: First start using a repository manager and don't try to reinvent a cache mechanism which is already well handled by repository managers...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, I'm already using Nexus. For most of the artifacts it's downloading metadata.xml. It's weird that for certain artifacts its not.

Comment: That sounds potentially like a bug (perhaps check/file on issues.sonatype.org).  However, both NXRM2 and NXRM3 should have a rebuild metadata scheduled task you might try first.  I am not sure why it wouldn't be generated in the first place unless it has to do with how you do part 1 (or a bug).